# React JS - onClick is creating an object within an object in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, setstate

I am making a React App for Ping Pong Tournament. Code below.

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";
import Button from "./Button";

const playerStylingTrue = {
    backgroundColor: "#26C281"
   };

class Matches extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
          numOfRounds: "",
          numberOfPlayers: this.props.numberOfPlayers,
          player1Clicked: false,
          player2Clicked: false,
          winners: []
          }

this.onClickWinnerP1 = this.onClickWinnerP1.bind(this);
this.onClickWinnerP2 = this.onClickWinnerP2.bind(this);
}

numberOfRounds() {
  const { numberOfPlayers } = this.state;
  const numOfRounds = Math.ceil((Math.log(numberOfPlayers)) / 
   (Math.log(2)));
  this.setState = ({
      numOfRounds: numOfRounds
      })
 };

onClickWinnerP1(player1) {
let player1String = player1.toString()
let { winners } = this.state;
// let findWinner = winners.find(o => o.player1String === player1);
//winners.includes(findWinner) ? null : 

  this.setState({
    player1Clicked: !this.state.player1Clicked,
    player2Clicked: this.state.player1Clicked,
    winners: [{...winners, player1String, winner:true}]
  })
};

onClickWinnerP2(player2) {
  let player2String = player2.toString()
  let { winners } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    player2Clicked: !this.state.player2Clicked,
    player1Clicked: this.state.player2Clicked,
    winners: winners.includes(player2String) ? [...winners] : 
[{...winners, player2String, winner:true}]
  })

};

 render() {
  const { pairs } = this.props;
  const { winners } = this.state;
  console.log(winners)
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Button
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
        className={"btn btn-success"}
        buttonText={"Create Random Matches "}
      />
      {pairs.map((pair, i) => {
          let player1 = [...pair];
          let player2 = player1.splice(0, Math.ceil(player1.length / 
        2));
        return (
          <div key={i} className="fixture-div">
            <ul className="list-unstyled fixture-list">
              <li
                style={ this.state.winners.includes(player1) ? playerStylingTrue : null}
                onClick={() => this.onClickWinnerP1(player1)}
                className="hvr-grow fixture">
                {player1}
              </li>
              <span>vs</span>
              <li
                style={this.state.winners.includes(player2) ? playerStylingTrue : null}
                onClick={() => this.onClickWinnerP2(player2)}
                className="hvr-grow fixture">
              {player2}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
    })
    }
    {/* <TwoRounds pairs={pairs}/> */}
  </Fragment>
   );
  }
 }

 export default Matches;
```

Currently the onClickWinnerP1 successfully add an object to the state, containing the correct details. However if I click twice or use onClickWinnerP2, is also adds an object to the state, but nested within the object that is already there. And so on, so on. Just keeps nesting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing setState in noOfRounds function isn't correct. Instead you should do like below

```
  this.setState({
     numOfRounds: numOfRounds
  })
```

Regarding your issue, do something like below in onClickWinnerP1 function to push objects into an array

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
   player1Clicked: !this.state.player1Clicked,
   player2Clicked: this.state.player1Clicked,
   winners: [...prevState.winners, {player1String, winner:true}]
}))
```

AND in onClickWinnerP2 function do something like below to push objects into an array

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    player2Clicked: !this.state.player2Clicked,
    player1Clicked: this.state.player2Clicked,
    winners: prevState.winners.includes(player2String) ? [...prevState.winners] : 
[...prevState.winners, {player2String, winner:true}]
  }))
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you! That is adding separate objects. I am now struggling to figure out the logic to only add it to the state if it is not already there.  Previously I was using array.includes but don't think I can use that as I am searching an array of objects?